# List search from within

Tags: c#, nested-lists

I have an object which has a list of other objects which has a list of yet another object.  My favorite example:

```
public class Artist
{
    int ArtistID;
    string ArtistName;
    List<Album> Albums;
}
public class Album
{
    int AlbumID;
    string AlbumName
    List<Song> Songs
}
public class Song
{
    int SongID;
    string SongName;
}
```

Since a song can be covered by many artists, I want to search for all artists that recorded a specific song.  I know this can be done using iteration, but I'm sure there's way to do it in a single statement.

`List<Artist> list` = all artists that sang "Yesterday"

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming a list of `Artist` called `artists` you're looking for

```
var yesterdaySingers = artists.Where(
       art => art.Albums.Any(
               alb => alb.Songs.Any(song => song.SongName == "Yesterday")
       )
).ToList();
```

Note you must add `using System.Linq;` to use the above.

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this using lambda statements.

```
var artists = artistList
   .Where(art => art.Albums.Any(alb => alb.Songs.Any(song => song.SongName == "Yesterday")))
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Brilliant! even the same variable names (almost). Great minds!

Comment: @Jamiec - that is uncanny, take an upvote :) And you beat me by 20 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I fear your data/class structure is inherently faulty.

> Since a song can be covered by many artists, I want to search for all artists that recorded a specific song. I know this can be done using iteration, but I'm sure there's way to do it in a single statement.

"Each artist can have multiple songs, and each song can have multiple aritsts", sounds like the book example of the [many-to-many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) relationship. However, what you have is two layers of 1:N.

You should change it so Song and Artist are in a proper N:M relationship, using a connection table.

Comment: If the different songs use the same primary key, I don't believe there is anything inherently 'wrong', as the above answers would work as intended, but you are correct in that using connection tables would be preferred. Especially with EFCore where it would be as simple as adding some .WithMany() methods to the DbContext configuration.